# Problem with complex numbers C||RLC

Tags: frequency, impedance, math, formula-derivation

I would like to bring this formula in the form Re(D) + jIm(D):

[image: C parallel RLC]

This is my current progress:

[image: progress]

My question is:

How can I get rid of the imaginary part jωC2*R?

When the denominator is completely real I can just split up the formula and have an imaginary and a real part.

Comment: ... By multiplying both numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate?

Comment: If you have new information to add to your question, edit into the original question rather than starting a new one.